# Expresión regular para comprobar paréntesis abierto y cerrado

Tags: javascript, regex

me gustaría formar una expresión regular para comprobar parentesis abierto y cerrado y que dentro de estos haya contenido por ej:

```
(Hola) <--- SI
() <--- NO
(a <--- NO
```

Encontré una para comprobar llaves abiertas y cerradas, pero no logro entender del todo como construir una expresión regular

```
{([^}]*)}
```

Y esa solo me detecta llaves abiertas y cerradas haya o no contenido en ellas.

Comment: Tienes que escapar los paréntesis: `\(.+?\)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hola, te dejo la expresión regular correcta y un ejemplo ejecutable.

```js
const regex = /(?:(?<=\().+?(?=\)))/gm;
console.log(regex.test("(hola)"));
console.log(regex.test("hola)"));
console.log(regex.test("()"));
console.log(regex.test("(hola"));
```